# Dapper, stored procedures and returning inserted row id via OUTPUT parameter

Tags: c#, t-sql, dapper

I have the following simple stored procedure:

```sql
create or alter procedure dbo.spAddAccount
    @AccountName varchar(100),
    @OpeningBalance money,
    @AccountTypeId tinyint,
    @AccountId tinyint output
as
begin
        
    insert into dbo.Accounts (AccountName, OpeningBalance, AccountTypeId)
    output inserted.AccountId
    values (@AccountName, @OpeningBalance, @AccountTypeId);
end
```

I'm calling it via Dapper from C# using the following code:

```cs
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("AccountName", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: account.AccountName);
parameters.Add("OpeningBalance", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: account.OpeningBalance);
parameters.Add("AccountTypeId", dbType: DbType.Byte, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value:account.AccountTypeId);
parameters.Add("AccountId", dbType: DbType.Byte, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        
await using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
await sqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(
    "spAddAccount",
    param: parameters,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

return parameters.Get<byte>("@AccountId");
```

This doesn't work, as `@AccountId` is always null.

If I run the stored procedure via a SQL shell like so:

```
declare @accountId tinyint;

exec spAddAccount 'Foo', 0, 1, @accountId output
select @accountId;
```

Then again, `@accountId` is always null.

I think it's because I need to assign the result of `output inserted.AccountId` to `@accountId`, as it's not smart enough to assign it to my declared output parameter. But I can't find how to do this.

I know I could use `scope_identity()`, but I was wondering how to get it working using `output` in the insert statement.

I also tried

```
output inserted.AccountId as '@AccountId`
```

but that's also no good.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the body of the stored proc

```sql
DECLARE @insertResult table (accountId tinyint)

insert into dbo.Accounts            
(AccountName, OpeningBalance, AccountTypeId)
OUTPUT INSERTED.AccountId into @insertResult
values
(@AccountName, @OpeningBalance, @AccountTypeId);

set @AccountId = (select accountId from @insertResult);
```

Comment: That's the way to do it - you need to capture the values from `OUTPUT` into a table variable. Since the `INSERT` generally *could* insert multiple rows at once, you cannot directly capture it into an atomic variable. But if you *know* from your app setup that only one row will be inserted, you can then read the value with  `SELECT @AccountId = (SELECT TOP 1 accountId FROM @insertResult)` and thus set your return value